# I want to understand how I can run a google app-script to extract information of schools in a certain state

Tags: sql, json, google-maps, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a database for all of the schools in a certain state. I have written a google app-script that pulls the details of a school and inserts it in a spreadsheet. The problem is that I want to automate the process of changing the name of the school in the url based on the ones I have.

I am also looking to extract the place_id based on a Lat and Long and with type=school but is not working and only pulls 20 schools:

```
function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();


ui.createMenu('Google Place Search')
      .addItem('Buscar Informacion','callgooglemapsapi')
      .addToUi();
}
function callgooglemapsapi() 
{

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=El%20Colegio%20de%20Tamaulipas&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,type,place_id,geometry,icon,id,name,permanently_closed,photos,place_id,plus_code,user_ratings_total&key=AIzaSyDQlB5xlLhSQZhdIkBGR0WXiWPLVqMwKkM");
  // Parse the JSON reply
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  Logger.log(data);
  Logger.log(data["candidates"]);
  Logger.log(data["candidates"][0]);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1,1).setValue(data["candidates"][0]["name"]);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 0,2).setValue(data["candidates"][0]["formatted_address"]);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 0,3).setValue(data["candidates"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 0,4).setValue(data["candidates"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 0,5).setValue(data["candidates"][0]["geometry"]["viewport"]["southwest"]["lng"]);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 0,6).setValue(data["candidates"][0]["geometry"]["viewport"]["southwest"]["lat"]);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 0,7).setValue(data["candidates"][0]["geometry"]["viewport"]["northeast"]["lng"]);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 0,8).setValue(data["candidates"][0]["geometry"]["viewport"]["northeast"]["lat"]);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 0,9).setValue(data["candidates"][0]["place_id"]);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 0,10).setValue(data["candidates"][0]["photo_reference"]);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 0,11).setValue(data["candidates"][0]["plus_code"]);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 0,12).setValue(data["candidates"][0]["types"]);
```

I expect to extract the detail information and photos and insert them to a spreadsheet, I have 4,000 school names.

Comment: I'm sorry, how does this give you 20 schools as written? Do they all have the same name?

Comment: If your key is supposed to be private you might want to remove it from the post.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect that it will look something like this:

```
function getSchoolData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('SchoolNames');//assume names in column A
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow-1,1);//skip header assume 1 row
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var shB=ss.getSheetByName('SchoolData');
  var vB=[]
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    vB.push(callgooglemapsapi(vA[i][0],sh));
    Utilities.sleep(milliseconds);//you may need a delay in here
  }
  shB.getRange(2,1,vB.length,vB[0].length).setValues(vB);
}


function callgooglemapsapi(schoolname,sheetname) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(sheetname)||ss.getActiveSheet();
  var baseUrl="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json"
  var key="AIzaSyDQlB5xlLhSQZhdIkBGR0WXiWPLVqMwKkM";
  var qs="?input=" + encodeURIComponent(schoolname) + "&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,type,place_id,geometry,icon,id,name,permanently_closed,photos,place_id,plus_code,user_ratings_total&key="
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl + qs + key);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  return [schoolname,data["candidates"][0]["name"],data["candidates"][0]["formatted_address"],data["candidates"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"],data["candidates"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"],data["candidates"][0]["geometry"]["viewport"]["southwest"]["lng"],data["candidates"][0]["geometry"]["viewport"]["southwest"]["lat"],data["candidates"][0]["geometry"]["viewport"]["northeast"]["lng"],data["candidates"][0]["geometry"]["viewport"]["northeast"]["lat"],data["candidates"][0]["place_id"],data["candidates"][0]["photo_reference"],data["candidates"][0]["plus_code"],data["candidates"][0]["types"]];
}
```